Administrator account from trusted domain loses privileges in trusting domain over time
I have test environment with two separate forests: ORANGE and GREY. They have one-way forest trust with Orange domain being trusted and Grey domain being trusting. In other words, account me@orange.local can login to ws01.grey.local workstation.
I have a Domain Admin account (da@orange.local) from domain Orange who is also a member of BUILTIN\Administrators group on domain controllers of domain Grey.
The inter-forest trust passes validation checks and works fine - I can logon to dc1.grey.local with da@orange.local just fine and have quite some privileges on those DCs.
But over time those privileges disappear. That's it: I leave RDP session open on dc1.grey.local with da@orange.local, next morning I re-login this session, see all windows open as I left them last evening, but if I try to open some MMCs or even taskmgr, I'm getting an error windows saying that I "may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item".
If I exit the session properly and login once more, everything goes back to normal.
If I do gpresult /r /scope:user in OK-ish session, I'm getting seeing membership in these groups:

Domain Users
Everyone
BUILTIN\Users
BUILTIN\Pre-Windows 2000 Compatible Access
BUILTIN\Administrators
REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
This Organization
LOCAL
Protected Users
Domain Admins
Authentication authority asserted identity
High Mandatory Level

If I do the same command in a faulty session, bold text groups are missing. So, over time some important memberships vanish and many apps on domain controller become unavailable, but why is this happening?
PS. All systems are in a virtual environment on the same physical server with Windows Server RRAS doing routing between vSwitches. So all machines have zero communication issues.
Additional Info: DCs are Windows Server 2022 and sometimes they become completely unresponsive (like Start menu and elevated command prompt not working), 100% fresh install. Only reboot helps. This leads me to believe that the root cause is not Protected Users group related, but something entirely different.

The Kerberos ticket is expiring and renewal is either not attempted or failing. Members of Protected Users have a four hour TGT ticket lifetime, and a 10 hour service ticket lifetime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/protected-users-security-group

Yes, it crossed my mind. However, I didn't mentioned, but I have two DCs per domain, absolutely identical. And often I see inconsistency: they both have sessions started at the same time and both have tickets expired, yet admin account on one of them retain its group membership while on another I see problems described earlier. Also there is a time buffer between membership loss (tgt expiration) and actual access privileges failing (and I don't see any service tickets in user's context anyway)

Remove from Protected Users and see if you can still reproduce to isolate the cause.  I also concur with the cause proposed by Greg.  When I have inadvertently left an RDP session open for a protected users, disconnecting and RDP and reconnecting (without closing any items in the session) worked just fine.

Is the account in the Protected users group in both domains?

I removed account from Protected Users but it didn't solved the issue. But it seems that Windows 2019 is far more stable in this regard. The account cannot be in Protected Users in both domains since Protected Users has global scope and cannot hold objects other than from it's own domain.
